# How to checkout to another remote in GitHub?

Tags: git, github, git-remote, upstream-branch

I'm using two repositories on github named as origin and upstream.

I can checkout to different branch with `git checkout [branch-name]` only within origin.

I cannot checkout to another repo upstream.

I have used `-t` option but it didn't work.

The error message was:

> 'upstream/[branch-name]' is not a commit and a branch  '[branch-name]'
>   cannot be created from it

I've added two repositories as my remote.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: does [branch-name] exist in upstream, or are you trying to create it

Comment: try `git fetch upstream` and after that `git branch -a`. You should see your upstream branch as **upstream/[branch_name]** in the list. Then you can checkout to that with `git checkout upstream/[branch_name]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a `git fetch upstream`, followed by `git branch -avv`.

If you don't see `branch_name` (the branch you want to checkout from `upstream`), then double-check the refspec associated with `upstream`:

```
git config --local -l
```

You should see:

```
remote.upstream.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

If not, that would explain why you don't fetch *all* the branches from `upstream`.